# systemd-resolve resolves incorrectly inside a network namespace

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, network-namespace, systemd-resolve

I have an Ubuntu machine with a network namespace (ns1) connected to the host network namespace via veth. I created a MASQUERADE rule in iptables to access the internet and I can ping 8.8.8.8 from the network namespace.

When I do `dig google.com` from the host, it works and I see in the main interface:

```
08:03:02.376478 IP 10.0.10.40.51566 > 10.0.10.2.53: 48449+ [1au] A? google.com. (39)
08:03:02.378335 IP 10.0.10.2.53 > 10.0.10.40.51566: 48449 1/0/1 A 216.58.204.110 (55)
```

However, when I execute dig in the network namespace: `sudo ip netns ns1 dig google.com`, it does not work and this is what I see in the main interface of the host:

```
08:03:09.033958 IP 10.0.10.40.50888 > 10.0.10.2.53: 32798+ [1au] A? ip-10-0-10-40.eu-west-3.compute.internal. (69)
08:03:09.034152 IP 10.0.10.40.36297 > 10.0.10.2.53: 43961+ [1au] AAAA? ip-10-0-10-40.eu-west-3.compute.internal. (69)
08:03:09.034460 IP 10.0.10.2.53 > 10.0.10.40.50888: 32798 NXDomain 0/1/1 (144)
08:03:09.034460 IP 10.0.10.2.53 > 10.0.10.40.36297: 43961 NXDomain 0/1/1 (144)
08:03:09.034559 IP 10.0.10.40.50888 > 10.0.10.2.53: 32798+ A? ip-10-0-10-40.eu-west-3.compute.internal. (58)
08:03:09.034639 IP 10.0.10.40.36297 > 10.0.10.2.53: 43961+ AAAA? ip-10-0-10-40.eu-west-3.compute.internal. (58)
08:03:09.034837 IP 10.0.10.2.53 > 10.0.10.40.50888: 32798 NXDomain 0/1/0 (133)
08:03:09.034906 IP 10.0.10.2.53 > 10.0.10.40.36297: 43961 NXDomain 0/1/0 (133)
```

Why the request coming from the network namespace is not trying to resolve hostname `google.com` but hostname `ip-10-0-10-40.eu-west-3.compute.internal`? The latter is apparently the hostname of my Ubuntu machine

#### EDIT

If I stop systemd-resolve and add the upstream nameserver, it works. Therefore, it must be an issue with systemd-resolve

Comment: Use the FQDN `google.com.`. A FQDN always ends with a `.`! Not using a FQDN means you are using a relative domain name, which might be in your case `google.com.yourlocaldomain.`

Comment: Note that it does not look for `google.com.yourlocaldomain`. there is no google at all. I tried with the dot and same result

Comment: Then your DNS server is not resolving recursive. *bind9* DNS server has to be enabled to resolve recursive in its newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-resolve` will rewrite your DNS to point to it on 127.0.0.53 by default. It isn't reachable in the namespace you created so DNS lookups fail.

Try using `dig google.com. @1.1.1.1` and it should work, whether `systemd-resolve` is running or not.